# Best way to share data between Server/Client on same host?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, data-sharing

I'm making a multi-threaded UDP client/server application in Java and have run into a little snag. I have a 'solution' in mind, but I'm 90% sure that it is a patchy fix to this issue.

Let's call host 1's threads Client 1 and Server 1 (C1 & S1), and host 2's threads Client 2 and Server 2 (C2 & S2). All of these extend Thread and override run(), while the clients also include some other methods ( e.g. chat() to initiate a chat between hosts). I then start each respective client/server pair via a third class that calls start().

To get data flowing, I create a socket for the C1/S2 and C2/S1 pairs and send/receive UDP datagrams through it. However, my clients need to respond to the *other* client's chat message, and hence S1 must also talk to C1, and S2 to C2.

What would be the best way of setting this communication up? I thought that I could for example create another socket on localhost for each of these machines (based in the client class/thread), to have a single host's client/server threads talk to each other, but this seems more like a workaround rather than a solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you are moving in LocalArea only, you could use broadcast to recive the messages.

Comment: I would still need a socket open to receive that broadcast, no?

Comment: Yap exactly, one to send to broadcast and one that listens for broadcast events

Comment: Right. So regardless of the method I use, I would still need to create an additional pair of sockets at each host, correct?

Comment: uh sorry i forgott, it is actually possible to just open one listener, and use this listener to send to another listener. So each host needs only one socket. (Works only with udp) Look at the `sendTo` function.